# How to set function on ScriptScope

Tags: c#, .net, clr, ironruby

How can I set a delegate on a ScriptScope under IronRuby?
I tried the above code but I got an ArgumentException when calling the function.

```
scope.SetVariable("import", new Action<string>(DSLImport));

import "Data"
```

Also, how can I use the above code sending the block as a callback to C# code?

```
import "Data" do |f|
    f.foo = false
end
```

Answer (score 0):

I found a way that might not be the best, but works.
It's a extension method to ScriptScope:

```
public static void SetMethod(this ScriptScope scope, string name, Delegate method)
{
    scope.SetVariable(name + "__delegate", method);
    scope.Engine.Execute("def " + name + "(*args, &block)\nargs.push block if block != nil\n" + name + "__delegate.invoke(*args)\nend", scope);
}
```